# href link to js and validate user's profile to visit url

Tags: javascript, html, google-ajax-api

I have html href and linked to a function in js file.
From the html when user clicked, it will validate user's profile by country. If the user's profile= TH and SG it will open a url, else it will open b url.
Please help me. I do not know whats wrong with my code

```js
    /* API Completion */
    api.done(function (a, c, d) {
   
      console.log(a.d);

      
      var countryCode = "";

      function checkCountry(upp) {
        return upp.Key === "CountryCode";
      }

      var arrUPP = a.d.UserProfileProperties.results.filter(checkCountry);
      
      //btn.addEventListener("click", travel);
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
        //$('ul.nav li').click(function() 
            
          if (arrUPP.length > 0 && arrUPP[0].Value) {
            countryCode = arrUPP[0].Value;
          }

          else if (countryCode == "TH" && countryCode == "SG") {
            window.location.href = 'https://....a url';
       

          } else {
            window.location.href = 'https://....b url';
            return;
          }
      
      });
    //} 
  });
  api.fail(function (a, b, c) {
    var errorMessage = [];
    errorMessage.push(errorMessage);
    errorMessage.push("Error: " + a.responseJSON.error.message.value);

    alert(errorMessage.join("\n"));
  });
```

```html
<li class="main">
        <a class="travel" href="javascript:travel();"  target="blank">
           <i class="icon-travel"></i>
     <span>Country</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will never be true `countryCode == "TH" && countryCode == "SG"`. You expect one value to be both "TH" AND "SG". You probably meant to use `||`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have changed the code to  (countryCode == "TH" || countryCode == "SG") {
but it still goes to [about:blank] page

Comment: That is odd, what happens if you remove the "return" inside the else clause?